# How to install GMLAS driver, working for OGR command line tool?

Tags: ogr

Normally I run my OGR SQL syntax within OSGeo4W shell. I want to try out the GMLAS driver, but can´t find a distribution where it´s installed. I´m on windows. How do I install the GMLAS driver, working with OGR command line tool?

Comment: OSGeo4W and packeges from gis.internals both come with GMLAS driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GMLAS driver can not be installed. You need to install a GDAL distribution that has it built in.

The [conda-forge gdal](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal) distribution includes the GMLAS driver. There may be other distributions that include it, but I only use conda.

If you don't have conda installed, I suggest [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

```
conda create -c conda-forge -n gdal_with_gmlas gdal python and any other packages etc
conda activate gdal_with_gmlas
ogrinfo --formats|findstr GML

  GML -vector- (rw+v): Geography Markup Language (GML)
  GMLAS -vector- (rwv): Geography Markup Language (GML) driven by application schemas
```